# Hot Code Push doesn't work on device in Meteor

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I'm starting with mobile development with Meteor and currently facing this problem: when running **meteor run android-device**, any changes made aren't reflected on device, as they were supposed to be.

The project I'm running is the default one - no additional packages or plugins installed. My Meteor version is 1.0.3.1 running on Ubuntu 14.0.4 with only the android platform installed. The device I'm using is a lovely Nexus 4.

Although it doesn't work on device, the Hot Code Push works like a charm on both simulator and browser.

Any clues what is going on? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you passing your server's ip address in with `--mobile-server` when you run `meteor run android-device`?

Comment: Nope. Weird enough, running the code in the ~same~ setup (OS, mobile, Meteor are equal but PC is different) the hot code push works (I'm not passing the server's ip address as well). I'll try this way and give you the feedback as soon as possible.

Comment: Its also worth checking the logs, the hot-code push is a much slower on cordova, where it downloads everything first then reloads. This isn't an immediate process and can sometimes take a few minutes. On the browser its near-immediate and everything is downloaded after the refresh.